# How can chemists distinguish pure chemical element specimens that look almost "the same" as well as what deposit is what in a multimineral mined rock?

Tags: identification, minerals

As a non chemist I am most often charmed when visiting Wikipedia articles of chemical elements and see images of very pure specimens of element after element, proton by proton, and often also metal cube specimen made from smithing similar pure deposits.

The wiki article [Periodic table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodic_table) allows me to do so easily; here are some elements I found looking almost the same and don't think I personally could distinguish between them without some instrument:

- [molybdenum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molybdenum#/media/File:Molybdenum_crystaline_fragment_and_1cm3_cube.jpg) and [manganase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manganese#/media/File:Mangan_1-crop.jpg)
- [titanium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Titanium#/media/File:Titan-crystal_bar.JPG) and [chromium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromium#/media/File:Chromium_crystals_and_1cm3_cube.jpg)
- [rutenium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruthenium#/media/File:Ruthenium_a_half_bar.jpg) and [cadmium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cadmium#/media/File:Cadmium-crystal_bar.jpg)
- [sodium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium#/media/File:Na_(Sodium).jpg) and [aluminium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Aluminium-4.jpg)
- [silicone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silicon#/media/File:SiliconCroda.jpg) and [germanium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Germanium#/media/File:Polycrystalline-germanium.jpg)

### My problem

Generally all examples are of synthetic specimens of about `99.9%` purity but that me to wonder what test can a chemist make in a natural environment, say inside a natural cavemine, to determine which *natural deposit* contains what after the mining and positioning a seemingly multimineral natural deposit;
Of course, I understand that with natural deposits of mainly carbon or copper, or iron (water exposed and rusty) natural deposits, let alone with very pure specimens of these elements, it will be easy because of color, but I believe that generally or mostly color by itself won't be enough due to various color biases and I assume that today there are *in-place* very-accurate tests that can be done, especially for different parts of a multimineral deposits.

### My question

How can chemists distinguish pure chemical element specimens that look almost "the same" as well as what deposit is what in a multimineral mined rock?

Comment: Most elements are not mined pure. Those which are (say, gold and silver) are relatively easy to tell apart.

Comment: As you enjoy reading Wikipedia this entry may interest you https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_absorption_spectroscopy

Comment: I am quite sad this question got a downvote ; in my opinion, images of very pure deposits of elements might be one of the best ways to do **public understanding of science** ; I don't even call myself a chemistry amateur although I really like learning new things about chemistry in accessible terms for `general audience of chemistry knowledge` and here I tried to help others and myself get one of the most fundamental understandings about chemistry.

Comment: I’ll give you an upvote for making the point about facilitating public understanding of science! Maybe this link will be of interest: https://theodoregray.com/PeriodicTableDisplay/ . One minor thing: what you call deposits are usually called specimens. Also, manganese, ruthenium and silicon are mispelled.

Comment: @EdV thanks ! By specimen did you mean to any "a whole, mined, multimineral deposit" or just to a particular "sub deposit cutted out of a mined multimineral deposit"?

Comment: No. I mean element specimens such as the machined rods, arc-melted pellets, etc. shown at, e.g., this link: https://elementsales.com/ . Go there and look at cobalt or hafnium or whatever element you want. These are not mineral specimens and, like Ivan said, are not mined as pure elements.

Comment: Thanks @EdV I have just made the question more helpful for future readers (hopefully) by accessing the important distinction you presented, in the simplest words I could.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're describing is essentially the field of "qualitative inorganic analysis". That's a very broad subject, but a short description is that prior to the advent of advanced instrumentation, chemists developed extensive series of tests specifically to determine the elemental composition of samples.

For example, one would start with basic physical properties like color, density, and hardness, then look at reactions with heat, acids, bases, oxidants, etc. If the compound could be solubilized in any way, then one can look at how the solubility/color/etc is affected by addition of known cations and anions. If it was a geological specimen, then the location and the types of surrounding minerals would help inform the analysis as well.

A well trained inorganic chemist would have standard flow-charts of tests and could fairly confidently identify the elemental composition of common minerals and metals.

Answer (score 0):

The qualitative inorganic analysis is a science in itself. To know what sort of elements you have in your sample, you have to first make it react with an acid like concentrated nitric acid $HNO3$. At the end of the reaction, you obtain a solution and an insoluble substance. You filtrate the residue. And now you get a solution S1 and a deposit D1.

You add some other solution, say $HCl$, to the solution S1. This will produce a precipitate D2 and a solution S2, that you separate by filtration. 
Simultaneously you treat the deposit D1 by a new reactant, like $NaOH$. Part of the deposit is dissolved. You obtain a new solution S3 and an insoluble part D3, that you separate by filtration.

Afterwards, you treat each solution and deposit by a new reagent, to obtain a new solution and a new deposit. It is a long job. And I cannot describe to you how to separate all different metals of the periodic table. It takes months of lab study to master this technique. But the principle is the same overal. At the end you obtain a precipitate which contains only one element. By weighing it, or by titration, you can determine its weight. You may need a lot of different reagents to carry out the *n*th separation.